# What does the "kvm disabled by bios" message during the boot process mean?

Tags: boot

I get this message during booting of my laptop:

```
[14.255596] kvm disabled by bios
```

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 15):

Well, is more or less what the error says. [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) is a Kernel-based Virtual Machine and some BIOS block the instructions that KVM uses. You can try some fixes in case that your BIOS is blocking it and the BIOS has KVM enabled:

> - On some hardware (e-g HP nx6320), you need to power-off/power-on the    machine after enabling virtualization in the BIOS.
> - Enabling some BIOS features may break VT support on some hardware    (e-g Enabling Intel AMT on a Thinkpad T500 will prevent kvm-intel
>     from loading with "disabled by bios")
> - On some Dell hardware, you also need to disable "Trusted Execution",    otherwise VT will not be enabled.

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#.22KVM:_disabled_by_BIOS.22_error

Answer (score 1):

In my case, an IBM T60, it was a bios-setting about the CPU, that had to be enabled. "When enabled, a WMM can utilize the additional hardware capabilities provided by Intel (R) Virtualization Technology."

Comment: What is a `WMM`?

Answer (score 0):

To enable KVM capability for a Toshiba Portege R705-P35, go to the BIOS's **Advanced** page, then, for the "**Virtualization Technology**" setting, select "**VT-⁠x Only**".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_(VT-x)